# How to enable SOCKS 5 authentication in Network Proxy Preferences

Tags: proxy, networking

Is there a way to add SOCKS 5 authentication to the Network Proxy Preferences dialog ?

Currently it supports only HTTP authentication.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `tsocks`

This programm socksifies each programm.
This is indeed only a workaround.

But in the tsocks config you can supply an user + password

It's shame but i think you have to create for each programm a startscript which starts it using tsocks

http://linux.die.net/man/5/tsocks.conf

http://www.ubuntux.org/evolution-using-a-socks-proxy

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the only workaround for now. I'll mark this as the correct answer if I don't get a better solution